# variable expansion in echo and terminal

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

Bash version:

```
debian@debian:~$  bash --version |grep release
GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Variable expansion in echo:

```
debian@debian:~$  a=apple
debian@debian:~$  echo '"'$a'
'
"apple

debian@debian:~$
```

I type `'"'$a'` and `newline` and `'`,echo parse it as three parts `'"'`,`$a`,`'newline'`,so it is `"`,`apple`,`\n`.What i analyse is the same as the output.Now remove the `echo` to see what happens:

Variable expansion in terminal:

```
debian@debian:~$  '"'$a'
> '
bash: $'"apple\n': command not found
```

Why terminal parse it as `$'"apple\n'`?

Comment: The parameter is still expanded. The only difference is whether the result is the argument to a command or the command itself.

Comment: In general, the command is whatever the first (non-assignment) word resulting from the various expansions the shell performs on the command line.

Comment: Are you familiar with [3.1.2.4 ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you hit enter to send a command line to the shell, it performs a variety of expansions (history, alias, parameter, etc), which produces a series of words. The name of the command to execute is the first word in that result that does not contain a `=` (or is not a predefined modifier like `time`).

In the first example, the first such word is `echo`, with the following word being the argument. The linefeed is written to the terminal, which "displays" it by moving the cursor to the beginning of the following line.

In the second example, the single word `$'"apple\n'` is the first such word. The `$'...'` is just how the shell *displays* a word with non-printable characters in its error message. It was decided that doing so would be clearer than

```
bash: "apple
: command not found
```